# Sync To Gradle, Android Studio 2021 Patch 2

Tags: android, gradle

I have an old Android Studio project that I need to resurrect briefly.

I've installed a fresh new copy of Android Studio, and unarchived the project into a location Android Studio can see. I need to sync to gradle, but I have no idea how to do this-- everywhere I should be able to see an option to do this (that I know about), there is no trace.

- I know it should be in the File menu.  It is not.
- I know I should be able to adjust the file menu with File, Setting, Menu and Toolbars-- that interface promises that 'sync project....' is in the File menu.  It is not.
- File, Settings, Plugins assures me gradle is installed.  Is it?  I don't know, can't prove it by me.
- File, Settings, Plugins also tells me I can use the gradle tool window through View, Tool Windows, Gradle.  No I cannot.  There is no such menu entry under View, Tool Windows.

Where the heck did they hide sync to gradle?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can double tap Shift and type "sync" to see the option.

[image]

2. You can find it at the top
   [image]

Comment: Nope.  1) gives me a menu, but not with an option to sync to grade.  2) That icon is simply not on the top toolbar.

Comment: I mentioned options you didn't list in your post. For example I can see it also in the file menu. But obviously there is a common problem with gradle in your project or maybe in your android studio installation.

Comment: I understand-- I'm not blaming you, just commenting that these are not working for me.  I have no idea what is going wrong.  Especially with a fresh new install of Android Studio.